# A way to create quality RTF formated tables with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rtf

I am working on an application using python 2.7 that should output rtf table..printable and nice formatted ..I tried **PyrtF** module but it is so complex and very limited for example ..I can not set colors with hex format ..however is there any way better?

Comment: PyRTF seems like a neat solution, did you check the examples: https://github.com/grangier/pyrtf/blob/master/examples/examples.py

Comment: it is still a solution but imagine you can not set colors other than red ,yellow,green,blue,and pink..looking for better